# Interface 'DatabaseStatementInterface' not found - Commerce Kickstart Installation

Tags: database, installation, commerce

I am trying to set up Commerce Kickstart distribution on a machine with following config:

- Apache 2.2.5
- PHP 5.5.5
- MySQL 5.1.71
- Oracle 11g

I see the welcome page at `http://example.com/install.php?profile=commerce_kickstart` but as soon as I click on `I accept`, the next page is a white screen.

I am seeing the following in the error logs:

```
[Thu Feb 27 03:18:18 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 27 03:18:29 2014] [error] [client 10.16.194.146] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'DatabaseStatementInterface' not found in /var/www/html/includes/database/prefetch.inc on line 22, referer: http://example.com/install.php?profile=commerce_kickstart
[Thu Feb 27 03:24:51 2014] [error] [client 10.16.194.146] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'DatabaseStatementInterface' not found in /var/www/html/includes/database/prefetch.inc on line 22, referer: http://example.com/install.php?profile=commerce_kickstart
[Thu Feb 27 03:24:52 2014] [error] [client 10.16.194.146] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Thu Feb 27 03:24:52 2014] [error] [client 10.16.194.146] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Thu Feb 27 03:26:42 2014] [error] [client 10.16.194.146] script '/var/www/html/install.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://example.com/install.php?profile=commerce_kickstart
[Thu Feb 27 03:26:46 2014] [error] [client 10.16.194.146] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
```

PHP Info shows that MySQL is configured.

Can anybody point to what the problem may be?

Comment: Check permissions of settings.php file..

Comment: Also, have you checked if that interface is defined? Maybe some files got malformed? And Drupal 7 recommends 5.3, there are some problems sometimes when using 5.5 - there was some backward-incompatible changes in 5.3 -> 5.4 upgrade. It should not be the case here, but it's something worth knowing none the less.

Comment: @AnilSagar - permissions are 644 for settings.php

Comment: @Mołot - The interface is defined and the file is complete. Will check with the drupal site for incompatibility with php 5.5.5

Comment: FWIW I run all my Drupal sites on PHP5.5.9 with absolutely no problems